# Android - skia decode error for images

Tags: android, image, skia

I have been trying to decode an image as follows:

```
            String dat = jobJect.getString("dat");
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String url2 = url1 + dat;
            request = new HttpGet(url2);
            request.setHeader("Cookie", "hcsid=" + GlobalConfig.hcSid);
            response = client.execute(request);
                            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(
                    response.getEntity());
            InputStream im = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

                    OutputStream out = null;

                    final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
                    CameraActivity.copy(im, out);
                    out.flush();

                    final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
                    mBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

Although I get an image, it doesn't get decoded and throws this error:

09-29 11:27:38.675: DEBUG/skia(14907): --- decoder->decode returned false

I'm following this code which handles a skia error:
http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/util/ImageUtilities.java

But it doesn't solve the issue.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this bug report:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9064